# Does Postgres guarantee to lock rows in the order of supplied update-statements?

Tags: postgresql

I like to do batch updates to Postgres. Sometimes, the batch may contain update-statements to the same record. (*)

To this end I need to be sure that Postgres locks rows based on the order in which the update-statements are supplied.

Is this guaranteed?

To be clear, I'm sending a sequence of single row update-statements, so not a single multi-row update-statement. E.g.:

```
update A set x='abc', dt='<timeN>' where id='123'; 
update A set x='def', dt='<timeN+1>' where id='123'; 
update A set x='ghi', dt='<timeN+2>' where id='123';
```

*) This might seem redundant: just only save the last one. However, I have defined an after-trigger on the table so history is created in a different table. Therefore I need the multiple updates.

Comment: If that is a single transaction, then there is only a single lock held by postgres (assuming `id` is the primary key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows will definitely be locked in the order of the `UPDATE` statements.

Moreover, locks only affect concurrent transactions, so if all the `UPDATE`s take place in one database session, you don't have to be afraid to get blocked by a lock.

Comment: Awesome. So in the above example, update-statement 1 will lock row with id=123. Update-statements 2 and 3 can't proceed because they affect the same row. After update-statement 1 is done it releases the row lock, so update-statement 2 can acquire the lock and start executing, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct if the three statements run in different database sessions. If the statements run concurrently, there is no clear order in which they get executed, but they will get executed one after the other. If they run in one transaction, they won't lock each other out.

Comment: Oh hmm. So to be clear, I want to run the above statements in 1 database session. This would mean they would run concurrently, and there's no clear order correct? What if I want to enforce the order of the statements as supplied? I.e.: statement with ` dt='<timeN>'` should run before  `dt='<timeN+1>'` should run before  `dt='<timeN+2>'`. Is this in any way possible?

Comment: No, if they run in a single database session, they are executed one after the other from top to bottom. Locks don't enter into the picture.